# Infinity symbol in TextBlock

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, unicode, ivalueconverter

I need infinity symbol in `TextBlock`

If I write `"&#8734;"` in `TextBlock.Text` all good, in `TextBlock` "∞" symbol.

```
<TextBlock Text="&#8734;"/>
```

But if I use `Converter`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyValue, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
```

I have `"&#8734;"` text in `TextBlock`.

```
 public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {           
           return "&#8734;";           
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: I believe that in your converter you are returning the XML encoded version of infinity, but it should be returning the raw infinity symbol?

Comment: thank, Sliver2009 gave answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this topic on stackoverflow:
[Does C# have something like PHP's mb_convert_encoding()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549006/does-c-sharp-have-something-like-phps-mb-convert-encoding)

```
string a = "ɢ♠♤ä<>&'\"";
string b = HtmlEntities.Encode(a);
Console.WriteLine(b); //&#610;&spades;&#9828;&auml;<>&'"
Console.WriteLine(HtmlEntities.Decode(b)); //ɢ♠♤ä<>&'"
```

So if you have a string with htmlEntities you can use

```
return HtmlEntities.Decode("& #8734;");
```

Answer (score 12):

`&#8734;`, aka `&#x221E;` is an XML character reference, it is turned into the character U+221E `∞` when the XML file containing it is parsed. However outside of XML, in a C# string literal, the `&#` sequence means nothing special, just an ampersand and hash. String literals in C# use the backslash character for their escapes rather than XML-style character references so to include an infinity sign in an ASCII-safe string literal:

```
return "\u221E";
```

Or if your editor and compiler agree on source code encoding, you can say simply:

```
return "∞";
```