# How to convert php's mb_convert_encoding() to C# equivalent

Tags: c#, php, hash, md5

I have tried rather unsuccessfully , to convert the following php code to C#
and require help please.

php code is

```
$string="012014Te$ting#501834502014060007400";
$salt = "Cli3ntH@sah";
$utfString=mb_convert_encoding($string.$salt,ÄSCII");
$hashTag=sha1($utfString,true);
$Hash = base64_encode($hashTag);
```

with C# code

```
    byte[] ascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objtohash);
    byte[] utf8 = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, Encoding.UTF8, ascii);
    byte[] hashBytes2 = sha1.ComputeHash(utf8);
    var Hash  = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes2);
```

also tried this, where objtohash = $string.$salt  (i.e. concatenated)

```
var sha1 = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed();
//convert to ascii byte array
byte[] AScii = EncodeAscii(objtohash);
//Hash it
byte[] hashBytes = sha1.ComputeHash(AScii);
//convert it to base 64
var Hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
```

I have tried several other ways as per SO, but I cannot get the same hashed value as the php sample.Hopefully someone can do it and hopefully give explanation as to why.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C# have something like PHP's mb\_convert\_encoding()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549006/does-c-sharp-have-something-like-phps-mb-convert-encoding)

Comment: there is syntax error here? `$utfString=mb_convert_encoding($string.$salt,ÄSCII");`

Comment: Please provide original, expected and the wrong value.

Comment: In php you use sha1 function on **ASCII** string, but in C# on **UTF8** string

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error was finger trouble.

The answer it turns out, ..basically by trying any and all combinations of what i could find by googling is:

```
        var objtohashArry = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(objtohash);
        var HashSharresult = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(objtohashArry);
        var requestHash = Convert.ToBase64String(HashSharresult);
        RequestHash = requestHash;
```